# Git/Windows: Possible for Two Users to Share the Same Folder?

Tags: windows, git, version-control

In my scenario, I have two people that do work on the same code base. Their only available workspace is a shared dev environment (where the files built are used to host the dev version of the site to boot). As such, they perform their work directly in that location. I've recently introduced source control to the project, and turned that location into a Git repository.

Let me preface by saying: Yes, I would love it if the dev host spot was a deploy-to spot, and these people had their own local copies of the source code. But that isn't feasible right now.

**My question**: Is it possible for two different Windows users/Git users (they have separate accounts that they can use to interact with GitHub/etc. with) to share the same folder? My hope would be that SourceTree (our weapon of choice) or Git, at least, wouldn't have a problem with this: Just show diffs of what's changed, and use the currently-logged-in user's information when making commits/other actions.

Comment: You could define [git environment variables](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables) for each user  and ask them to only commit files they modified (and ideally only the part of the file they edited using `add -e`) but it will definetly beget more work to your team. To use distinct logins, prefer HTTPS  to SSH which is requesting the user login for each push/pull.

Comment: It's a weird thing to do so there is no certainty. Try but it should work because user git config is stored in the user profil folder (so per user)

Comment: Since git is DVCS (Distribute Version Control System), that mean it works in the local copies, and then push the local commit to remote repo. If you want two users share the local copies, you can located the local repo in shared directory which the two users can access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that while SourceTree has separate installation directories, it still embeds some account information in the `.git` folder itself. When I try to interact with Git (via a `pull` for example), it first tries to prompt for new credentials/etc., but shortly thereafter it says "please enter password for {other-user}" without an option to hop usernames.

It looks like we'll just have to do things the right way after all. Painful (for them) but no choice.